# Fastlane: snapshot. Where is the temp folder

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

Where is the temp folder for the images that are created during the process of the fastlane: snapshot tool?

Answer (score 1):

The final location for *snapshot* screenshots is controlled by the `output_directory` option. However, I get the sense you're wondering where the files live before that?

Before that, screnshots wind up in a temporary location defined by the `derived_data_path` option. If no `derived_data_path` is provided a random system-generated temporary folder will be used. Once that temporary location is determined, screenshots will be in a sub-folder called **Attachments**

Answer (score 0):

temp folder is always in doc. directory If you are using real IOS device for testing It will be in Xcode -- > window -- > Device--> select your Device -- > Godown to setting Icon --> download Container -- > Once it downloaded right Click and show package Content --

You will find the temp folder.

Comment: oh. sorry for the confusion. i mesn the local temp folder of the snapshot tool on the mac